# how to append to a struct from a button

Tags: swift

I have a struct, and have created a button in which I want to write something and then append the writing to my struct.
I'm having trouble with how to write a correct code so that I append correctly the text from the button into my struct.

here is my struct:

```
 struct Candy{
  let category : String
  let name : String
}

 candies = [
  Candy(category:"test", name:"test 2"),
  Candy(category:"test", name:"test 4"),
  Candy(category:"test", name:"test 1"),
  Candy(category:"Music", name:"J-cole"),
  Candy(category:"Music", name:"Jay-z"),
  Candy(category:"Music", name:"Coldplay"),
  Candy(category:"Other", name:"Sophie"),
  Candy(category:"Other", name:"Frederic"),
  Candy(category:"Other", name:"test")]

    }
```

And this is the code for my button:

```
   @IBAction func addBar(sender: AnyObject) {

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "New name",
                                  message: "Write name",
                                  preferredStyle: .Alert)

    let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Save",
                                   style: .Default,
                                   handler: { (action:UIAlertAction) -> Void in

                                    let textField = alert.textFields!.first

                                    self.candies.append(textField!.text!) // I have troubles with this line... not sure how to make this line correct..


                                    self.tableView.reloadData()
```

Comment: That's not a struct, it's an `Array` of `Candy` Structs, written as: `Array<Candy>`, or `[Candy]` for short.

Comment: Side note: `category` would probably be better off as an `enum`. See the language guide section on `enum`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create an instance of the struct `Candy` in order to add it to the array `candies` of type `Candy`, like in this way:

```
self.candies.append(Candy(category:"NameYouWant", name: textField!.text!))
```

In the above I suppose you want to the save the `textField!.text!` as the name property in the `Candy`, but you can change it as you want.

I hope this help you

Comment: I now I get a new error:  This class is not key value coding-compliant for the key addBar.'

Comment: You've experimenting another error very different from the issue you asked, see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088059/what-does-this-mean-nsunknownkeyexception-reasonthis-class-is-not-key-valu

Answer (score 0):

Your problem line is trying to add a simple string to the array where is should create a new instance of your struct and add that. It isn't clear exactly how that should work as you have 1 string and the struct takes 2, but it's something like:

```
self.candies.append(Candy(category: "xxx", name: textField!.text!))
```